# Flutter: (iOS) Text Form Field for email address autocapitalizes names

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

[Video of behavior](https://youtu.be/2mZ2xj9JWvA)

I'm implementing a basic login screen in my flutter app and I'm running into a pretty annoying issue. My email address is lastName.firstName@.... and without fail, as soon as I type the '.' after my last name, it auto capitalizes the first letter. I've tested it with some other names and it seems like it happens for some and not for others. My text form field widget is defined as:

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: _email,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'email'),
),
```

Is this just something OS controlled or is it fixable? I've only tried it in the iOS sim, but I'm assuming the behavior would be similar on an actual device.

If there isn't a definitive fix does anyone have an idea about a workaround?

I tried changing the widget to this:

```dart
TextField(
  controller: _email,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'email'),
  onChanged: (value){
    _email.text = value.toLowerCase();
  }
)
```

This sort of worked, but it seems hacky. It messed up the cursor position and occasionally got stuck just flashing text when I typed the '.'. Sorry if it's a pretty basic question, I'm just starting out with Flutter and mobile app development in general. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you simply remove `textCapitalization` parameter ?

Comment: @DK15 It is by default `TextCapitalization.none` so that won't make a difference.

Comment: @DK15 Yeah, unfortunately I've tried it both ways. I added TextCapitalization.none originally to try to fix the issue to no avail. I've never noticed this behavior before in some of the Swift apps I've worked on, but maybe I'm just not remembering correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must know someone whose name is Jane; the field is auto-correcting. Add

```
autocorrect: false,
```

to your email text field.

Comment: Interesting! That makes sense though. I'll try this out and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue and this actually fixed it for me

Comment: @flutter, I'm sorry it didn't work for you.  Do you have an example that shows your problem?  "tried, doesn't work" doesn't provide a lot of detail.

Answer (score 1):

The `textCapitalization` parameter is only responsible for showing the right keyboard. In the case of `TextCapitalization.none` it will show a keyboard containing only lowercase characters.
It is possible to prevent the system keyboard from updating the text for you by validating/formatting the input using `TextInputFormatter`,

see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html